# White and black testpage

Tags: printing

I am trying to print with a printer which uses kyocera3253ci driver.
Printing options are set to Full Color but when I print the test page, it turns out white and black. The printer works perfectly with Mac OS.

Comment: the only os you mention is off topic here.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted to underline the fact that this is not a problem related to the printer

Comment: Did you check that the driver in CUPS http://localhost:631/ is good and that the defaults are all set correctly for your printer?

Comment: Yes, in CUPS the installed driver is CS 3253ci KPDL (color, 2-sided printing) and the default option is full color